# My site is showing the wrong ssl certificate

Tags: ssl, https

A few weeks ago I was setting up an SSL certificate on my domain. When doing this in dreamhost it creates a self signed one to use before the signed one is created and ready to be used, it then allows you to select the signed one instead of the self signed one.

Well I accessed my site between then to check something and even after using the signed one every browser I try to access the site in tells me it's a bad SSL certificate and I just see a "Site not found" dreamhost page.

Everyone else in my office can access the site normally, and no matter what browser I try I cannot get to the site at all. I've tried a few different things but I can't get anything to allow me to access this site and have it see that it's no longer using the self signed certificate anymore.

Comment: Maybe you have accidentally removed or permitted the root certificate?

Comment: In my dreamhost panel I see under secure hosting that it's using the professionally signed certificate. When I go to the site and check the certificate details on someone else's computer who can access it it showing the correct;y signed certificate. But on mine it shows a self signed certificate.

Comment: Try deleteing the certificate cache, should be here http://support.microsoft.com/kb/290345

Comment: Forgot to mention I'm on mac, I googled and don't see an equivalent method for mac.

Comment: Do you have imported the self signed certificate on your mac? If so try to remove it. (Keychain Management)

Comment: Yeah I just found a link talking about that, I checked in keychain and can't find the cert it says that it's using.